# Trapping errors using catch

Tags: tcl

When reading about catch in mutliple references, all the examples seem to be very simple one-liners such as:

```
if { [catch {...} result] } { 
  # Handle error
}
```

What if the script is a bit more involved? The catch result will be the result of the script (the last line, it appears) not the return of `catch` itself. Do you use `return 0 -level 0` to make `0` the result of the script (if you don't need to get the script result that way) or test `[dict get $catchDict -code]`? What it the proper way to catch errors for more than a single line of code?

Thank you for considering my question.

```
catch {
  # A few lines of code.
  return 0 -level 0
} catchResult catchDict

if { $catchResult } { 
  # Handle error.
}
# OR
if { [dict get $catchDict -code] } {
  # Handle error.
}
```

Comment: `catchResult` is the result of the few lines of code. It's not actually the result of the `catch` command itself. `catch` returns zero (a false value) to mean "no errors" and a non-zero value to mean "errors occurred". See [this extensive example](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec#1a39e854c66866d4b4567dcb8126b8f0914bdab191eea3a4812f3ca8d9d2bff3) in the Tcl Wiki page for `exec`.

Comment: Thank you. I see the try/trap there also.

Comment: Conceptually, Tcl results are a tuple or dictionary of things. The main ones are the return code (OK, error, a few other things) and the result (the value or error message) and there are a few others (e.g., the accumulating stack trace of an error). `catch` lets you pick that up. `try` provides a different way to do it. The first version of `try` was just a procedure that used `catch`; it's bytecoded now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For trapping errors on bigger blocks of code, you can use the [`try`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.html) command:

```
try {
    # A few lines of code
} on error {catchResult catchDict} {
    # Handle error
}
```

This command also allows you to differentiate error causes by using `trap` handlers and perform some cleanup via a `finally` script.

Answer (score 1):

If no error is caught, `result` will get the value computed by the code.  If an error is caught `result` will get the error message. So usually all you need is

```
if {[catch {
  # A few lines of code.
} result]} {
  # Handle error, e.g. puts stderr $result
} else {
  # do something with result
}
```